# fixPluralClassNames option not working when generating through visual studio

Tags: subsonic

I have a table in my database called "Campus" and when sonic.exe generates the class it names it "Campu". So I tried setting "fixPluralClassNames" to false in my generate statement (through visual studio as an external command, it automatically picks up the connection strings in app.config) but it still generates it as "Campu". I tried running sonic.exe manually through the command line (passing it my database info using /server and /db), setting "fixPluralClassNames" to false and it correctly generates the class named "Campus". Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do other configuration options work if you specify them in your app.config?

Comment: You could name your table "campuss" ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways: set it in your App.Config (where you SubSonicService is setup) or you can pass it in to sonic.exe when you make the call - as you've seen. I would say to just put it in your config.

Comment: Thanks. It worked when I put it in my App.config, although I had to put it in the specific provider, not the SubSonicService line.